# Check if chars of a string contains in another string with LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

I'm making a Scrabble game in the command line with C#. The player must input some words like list below:

| Word | Points |
| --- | --- |
| some | 6 |
| first | 8 |
| potsie | 8 |
| day | 7 |
| could | 8 |
| postie | 8 |
| from | 9 |
| have | 10 |
| back | 12 |
| this | 7 |

The letters the player got are this:

```
sopitez
```

This value is a string. I'll check if the letters contains in the words. For this I've tried this code:

```cs
String highst = (from word
                 in words 
                 where word.Contains(letters)
                 orderby points descending
                 select word).First();
```

But it doesn't work how I'll it. This code wouldn't select any word. I know the reason why because `sopitez` doesn't contain in any word.

My question now is there a way to check the chars in the string `letters` contain into the words whitout looping over the chars.

**Note:** Each letter must be used at most once in the solution.

If I calculate the result it must be `potsie` or `postie`. *(I must write the logic for that)*

<sup>**P.S.:** I'm playing this game: [www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/scrabble](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/scrabble)</sup>

Comment: Could you give us a example of a calculation ?

Comment: You should check if their [Intersection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Contains` checks to see if one string contains another; it is not checking to see if it contains all of those characters.  <strike>You need to replace each string in your dictionary with a `HashSet<char>` and perform set comparisons like `IsSubset` or `IsSuperset` to determine if the letters are matching.</strike>

Here is what you're doing:

```
string a= "Hello";
string b= "elHlo";
bool doesContain = b.Contains(a); //This returns false
```

<strike>Here is what you need to do:</strike>

```
var setA = new HashSet<char>(a);
var setB = new HashSet<char>(b);    
bool isSubset = a.IsSubsetOf(b); //This returns true
```

**Update**
Actually, this is wrong, because sets remove duplicate elements.  But essentially you are misusing `Contains`.  You'll need some more complicated sequence comparison that can allow duplicate letters.

**Update2**
You need this for word/letters comparison:

```
//Compares counts of each letter in word and tiles
bool WordCanBeMadeFromLetters(string word, string tileLetters) {

    var tileLetterCounts = GetLetterCounts(tileLetters);
    var wordLetterCounts = GetLetterCounts(word);

    return wordLetterCounts.All(letter =>
        tileLetterCounts.ContainsKey(letter.Key)
        && tileLetterCounts[letter.Key] >= letter.Value);
}

//Gets dictionary of letter/# of letter in word
Dictionary<char, int> GetLetterCounts(string word){
    return word
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .ToDictionary(
            grp => grp.Key,
            grp => grp.Count());
}
```

So your original example can look like this:

```
String highst = (from word
             in words 
             where WordCanBeMadeFromLetters(word, letters)
             orderby points descending
             select word).First();
```

Comment: Must it be `setA.IsSubsetOf(setB)` instead of `a.IsSubsetOf(b)`?

Comment: I thought he was trying to calculate a "score of sorts" except for the words that have been fully matched...

Comment: The problem is in filtering which words can actually be played.  He was filtering with `Contains` which was excluding all his words, because it does not check for letter counts/combinations, it checks for substrings.

Comment: Yup, totally understand. I just misread his post the first time (lol)

Answer (score 3):

This will not be performant at all but at least it will do the trick. Notice that I've used a dictionary just for the sake of simplicity <del>(also I don't see why you would have repeated words like "potsie", I've never played scrabble).</del> You can as well use a list of Tuples if you follow this code

**EDIT:** I changed this according to the OP's new comments

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var letters = new HashSet<char>("sopitez");

        var wordsMap = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"some", 6}, {"first", 8}, {"potsie", 8}, {"postie", 8}, {"day", 7},
            {"could", 8}, {"from", 9}, {"have", 10}, {"back", 12},
            {"this", 7}
        };

        var highest = wordsMap
            .Select(kvp => {
                var word = kvp.Key;
                var points = kvp.Value;
                var matchCount = kvp.Key.Sum(c => letters.Contains(c) ? 1 : 0);
                return new {
                    Word = word,
                    Points = points,
                    MatchCount = matchCount,
                    FullMatch = matchCount == word.Length,
                    EstimatedScore = points * matchCount /(double) word.Length // This can vary... it's just my guess for an "Estiamted score"
                };
            })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.FullMatch)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.EstimatedScore);


        foreach (var anon in highest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", anon);
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: (just nitpicking) you don't really need the lambda ; using the method group is enough : `Any(letters.Contains)`

Comment: Thanks! Pity I don't have ReSharper in dotnetfiddle :D

Comment: No, it doesn't give me the result I'll have. The result of your code is `have`. The result must be `postie` or `potsie`.

Comment: So you can have repeated words? And what do you do with the points for repeated entries, sum them?

Comment: I see now, there are no duplicates, you `postie` != `postie`... and you probably want to have the word that matches most of the characters of the input stream, let me fix that :P

Comment: Yes indeed. That's true. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since letters can repeat, I think you need something like this (of course that's not very efficient, but pure LINQ):

```
var letters = "sopitezwss";

var words = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
    {"some", 6}, {"first", 8}, {"potsie", 8}, {"day", 7},
    {"could", 8}, {"from", 9}, {"have", 10}, {"back", 12},
    {"this", 7}, {"postie", 8}, {"swiss", 15}
};

var highest = (from word
    in words
    where word.Key.GroupBy(c => c).All(c => letters.Count(l => l == c.Key) >= c.Count())
    orderby word.Value descending
    select word);
```