# Need to check a key in a dictionary for the letters of a string

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

So I have a dictionary and need to check each key entry to see if it contains a series of letters in a string(lets call this LETTERS). If the key has any letters that LETTERS does not, or it has more of a letter than LETTERS has, it has to be removed.(LETTERS is not known beforehand)
This is the code involved

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordHolder = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string LETTERS = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < LETTERS.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < wordHolder.Count; j++)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is the order of LETTERS relevant? You may put a real example so we can see what you want to achive

Comment: can you provide an example of what wordholder and LETTERS would contain please.

Comment: I guess you want to check key exists in you collection or not right?

Comment: @Wheels73 an example of a wordholder key would be **could** and LETTERS **hicquwh**

Comment: @Pikoh the order of LETTERS isnt relevant just need to check each letter it gives

Comment: So, what you want to check if the key is a combination of the letters in LETTERS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if chars of a string contains in another string with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076904/check-if-chars-of-a-string-contains-in-another-string-with-linq)

Comment: @Pikoh yeah thats correct

Comment: Hello.. think we just need clarification on "need to check each key entry to see if it contains a series of letters in a string(lets call this LETTERS)". With your example we would check all keys to see if any one key = "hicquwh" or just contains "hicquwh"?   You then say "If the key has any letters that LETTERS does not".. which implies your checking each key on a letter by letter basis to see if it has any of "hicquwh"?

Comment: @Wheels73 Im just trying to check if the key entry can be made using the letters of LETTERS. it then needs to be able to remove the Dictionary entry if the key cannot be made using the LETTERS. If it can then i want to leave it be

Comment: @TravisJeffery check the duplicate I just posted. It does exactly what you want

Comment: @TravisJeffery if I understand correctly you want to keep the "keys" that are anagrams of the letters given?

Comment: @jjchiw no, the "keys" have to be able to be made using them, but doesn't need to use all of them. For example **which** is the key being checked and the LETTERS given are **hicquwh** you can make which using the LETTERS and still have more leftover. this is okay but **because** would not work as it has letters that LETTERS has not provided and would have to be removed from the dictionary

Comment: @Pikoh I had a look at that, im not sure how i can use it to check the values of my dictionary to the LETTERS and then remove them?

Comment: Use the accepted answer `WordCanBeMadeFromLetters` method. You can just loop on all the Dictionary entries, call that method, and if it returns false, remove the entry from it.

Comment: @Pikoh I tried and its saying i cant convert keyValuePair to string at the WordCanBeMadeFromLetters part
`        String highst = (from word
             in wordHolder
                         where WordCanBeMadeFromLetters(word, LETTERS)
                         orderby points descending
                         select word).First();
`

Comment: Using that method, you could do something like `var resultDictionary = wordHolder.Where(x => WordCanBeMadeFromLetters(x.Key, letters)).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,p=>p.Value);`. This would return a dictionary with all the words that can be made with the letters

Comment: And if what you want is to get the max value of words that can be made with that letters: `var resultDictionary = wordHolder.Where(x => WordCanBeMadeFromLetters(x.Key, letters)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I've add an answer that seems to work if you still need one.

Comment: @TravisJeffery it's important the count/number/quantity of the characters? eg.the KEY *FFF* with LETTER *FF* does the KEY should be removed? since it's missing a third *F*....

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone, I managed to get it working with the answer from @Wheels73

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have it this time if you still need an answer

The below has 5 keys... 3 of which can not be created from the contents of "LETTERS".

```
 Dictionary<string, int> wordHolder = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            wordHolder.Add("CEFBA",1);
            wordHolder.Add("ZDFEEG",2);
            wordHolder.Add("TYHRFG", 3);
            wordHolder.Add("FFFFBBDD", 4);
            wordHolder.Add("PCDATTY", 5);

            var keysToRemove = new List<string>();

            string myLetters = "ABCDEF";

            var myLettersArray = myLetters.ToCharArray();

            foreach (var keyToCheck in wordHolder)
            {
                var keyCannotBeCreatedFromLetters = false;
                var keyArray = keyToCheck.Key.ToCharArray();

                foreach (var letterExists in 
                            from keyLetterToCheck in keyArray 
                                where !keyCannotBeCreatedFromLetters 
                                    select myLettersArray.Any(a => a == keyLetterToCheck) 
                                        into letterExists 
                                            where !letterExists select letterExists)
                {
                    keysToRemove.Add(keyToCheck.Key);
                    keyCannotBeCreatedFromLetters = true;
                }
            }

            foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
            {
                wordHolder.Remove(key);
            }
```

It correctly identifies the 2nd, 3rd and 5th key as not creatable.

Below is the same logic but as foreach loops. I find this often useful so you can see whats happening internally.

```
foreach (var keyToCheck in wordHolder)
            {
                var keyCannotBeCreatedFromLetters = false;
                var keyArray = keyToCheck.Key.ToCharArray();

                foreach (var keyLetterToCheck in keyArray)
                {
                    if (keyCannotBeCreatedFromLetters)
                        continue;

                    var letterExists = myLettersArray.Any(a => a == keyLetterToCheck);

                    if (letterExists) continue;

                    keysToRemove.Add(keyToCheck.Key);
                    keyCannotBeCreatedFromLetters = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks this has done it! you help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return any KeyValuePair which Key contains all letter inside LETTERS.

It would look like this:

```
 // Assuming 
 // Dictionary<string, int> wordHolder = new Dictionary<string, int>();  // Something
 // string LETTERS = ""; // Something

 List<char> listLettersToHave = LETTERS.ToList();
 Dictionary<string, int> researchResult = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in wordHolder)
 {
     List<char> listLettersYouHave = pair.Key.ToList();
     bool ok = true;

     // If not the same count go to next KeyValuePair
     if (listLettersToHave.Count != listLettersYouHave.Count)
         continue;

     foreach (char toCheck in listLettersToHave)
     {
         // Search first occurence
         if (!listLettersYouHave.Contains(toCheck))
         {
             ok = false;
             break;
         }

         // Remove first occurence
         listLettersYouHave.Remove(toCheck);
     }

     if (ok)
         // If all letters contained then Add to result
         researchResult.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
 }

 // if it's a function
 // return researchResult;
```

It's an example and you can improve it but the idea is here.

EDIT : 
If the dictionnary have for keys : `abc`, `cbda`, `dca`
An input of `bac`
The results key would be : `abc`

The solution is case sensitive but a `.ToUpper()` will solve the problem.

Using the previous example, if you want `cbda` to match you can remove the check on `Count`.

Comment: Sorry im having trouble understanding how i would use this? i tried adding it to the code and nothing happened?

Comment: Is that because you give nothing to your dictionnary? Comparing something to nothing the result will always be nothing :)

Comment: Sorry? i dont understand, Im trying to compare the Dictionary wordHolder